# AlertDialog causes java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, runtime, android-alertdialog

I'm getting this error after clicking the AlertDialog box OK Button to Intent to the next activity, the data is still being inserted into the database but the application just crashes.

Logcat error:

```
07-22 02:26:08.603: E/JSON(10170): {"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"500af44ea075b5.28543539","user":{"name":"Dddds","email":"Saasa","imei":"359616041330986","created_at":"2012-07-22 02:26:22","updated_at":null}}
07-22 02:26:08.623: E/JSON(10170): {"uid":"500af44ea075b5.28543539","error":0,"user":{"created_at":"2012-07-22 02:26:22","updated_at":null,"email":"Saasa","imei":"359616041330986","name":"Dddds"},"success":1,"tag":"register"}
07-22 02:26:08.758: D/dalvikvm(10170): GC_CONCURRENT freed 142K, 3% free 13469K/13831K, paused 7ms+2ms
07-22 02:26:09.608: D/dalvikvm(10170): newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1
07-22 02:26:09.608: D/AndroidRuntime(10170): Shutting down VM
07-22 02:26:09.608: W/dalvikvm(10170): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c681f8)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{nyp.android.project/nyp.android.project.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class nyp.android.project.DashboardActivity
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class nyp.android.project.DashboardActivity
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1026)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
07-22 02:26:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(10170):    ... 11 more
07-22 02:26:59.308: I/Process(10170): Sending signal. PID: 10170 SIG: 9
07-22 02:31:13.878: D/OpenGLRenderer(10938): Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-22 02:31:15.773: D/dalvikvm(10938): GC_CONCURRENT freed 155K, 3% free 13114K/13511K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-22 02:31:17.708: D/OpenGLRenderer(10938): Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-22 02:31:26.963: E/JSON(10938): {"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"500af58d0aa288.05836094","user":{"name":"Test","email":"Test","imei":"359616041330986","created_at":"2012-07-22 02:31:41","updated_at":null}}
07-22 02:31:26.968: E/JSON(10938): {"uid":"500af58d0aa288.05836094","error":0,"user":{"created_at":"2012-07-22 02:31:41","updated_at":null,"email":"Test","imei":"359616041330986","name":"Test"},"success":1,"tag":"register"}
07-22 02:31:27.008: D/dalvikvm(10938): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 214K, 3% free 13240K/13639K, paused 20ms
07-22 02:31:28.468: D/dalvikvm(10938): newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1
07-22 02:31:28.468: D/AndroidRuntime(10938): Shutting down VM
07-22 02:31:28.468: W/dalvikvm(10938): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c681f8)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{nyp.android.project/nyp.android.project.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class nyp.android.project.DashboardActivity
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class nyp.android.project.DashboardActivity
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1026)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
07-22 02:31:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(10938):    ... 11 more
```

Code:

```
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password, IMEI.getText().toString());

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registered
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this).create();

                        // Setting Dialog Title
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Registration");

                        // Setting Dialog Message
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Registration successful");

                        // Setting Icon to Dialog
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

                        // Setting OK Button
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();

                        }
                        });

                        // Showing Alert Message
                        alertDialog.show();     

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT), json_user.getString(KEY_IMEI));                     

                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class); in this use activity context instead of the Application context ....

Comment: Post the DashboardActivity code and make sure it's included in the manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen an intent created with getApplicationContext(). Did you try it using ClassName.this instead?

Usually it is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
```

Comment: Is DashboardActivity doing something crazy? :P

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it, it was something going crazy over at my DashboardActivity.java thanks anyway!

Comment: Haha, alright, that's why I asked about it; it seemed to be going in that direction. Np! However, I would keep in mind what we said about GetApplicationContext(). In most cases, you don't want to use that over the Activity's context.